# How to perform a search with multiple strings with RESTHightLevelCient

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I have a field which has multiple strings, how do I write a search query for that with the RESTHightLevelCient. Also, the search string i give is just a partial string.

---

Adding a little more detail.

I am trying to implement something where I have multiple columns, but just one search string. My search string can be a combination of different columns; also my search should work when the string is just the combination of partial words from different columns.

I am trying a solution to get this working, by having a single column which is a space-separated join of all the other searchable columns in the order they can appear in the search.

So if I have 4 columns, Bookname, Author, Price, and  Publication and when I give the partial book name with the partial author. I want the matches to be returned in the order where the most relevant match are on the top.

Comment: Why not using a simple match query? am i missing something?

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do a regexp search like this: (let the field name be "quotes" ):

```
BoolQueryBuilder searchFilter = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
searchFilter.must(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("quotes",".*err is to hum.*").flags(RegexpFlag.ALL));
```

This will return all quotes containing the expression "err is to hum" , for example a matching entry could be "To err is to human" .

`.*___.*`     is for contains search (put search exp in place of dash)

`.*___`        ends with

`___.*`       starts with

`~.*____.*`   not containing

Hope this helps.

Comment: what about if the search string is "er hum". Also, would the best approach be to use the "*"?